# What is Quint? I cloned a repo that mimics real raindrops on a glass wall. I tried to run it but gives me an error `Quint is not defined`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gsap

I cloned a repo `RainEffect` that mimics real raindrops on a glass wall.  I tried to run it but gives me an error `Quint is not defined` .  I installed all the node modules it contained.  Also tried `yarn build` `npm start` to initiate the application.  Then I traced the error below:

```
function setupParallax(){
  document.addEventListener('mousemove',(event)=>{
    let x=event.pageX;
    let y=event.pageY;

    TweenLite.to(parallax,1,{
      x:((x/canvas.width)*2)-1,
      y:((y/canvas.height)*2)-1,
      ease:Quint.easeOut,
      onUpdate:()=>{
        renderer.parallaxX=parallax.x;
        renderer.parallaxY=parallax.y;
      }
    })
  });
}
```

The error says: `Quint is not defined`  So I tried `install npm install --save Quint` and says:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: Quint@latest
```

Please Help - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

https://greensock.com/docs/Easing/Quint

you can add GSAP using NPM

npm install gsap

More information about the package can be found below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap

Comment: clark, thanks for the response.  Still cant make it work and have the same errors.

Comment: Try npm install gsap this should install the required dependancies for you :)

Comment: Then your JS needs compiling. Is there any errors. Such as.. require x ??